# Combining plots with added lines using par()

Tags: facet, par

I have a produced a nice 4 panel display of hist plots for variables in my dataset using par(), and I also have learned to add a normal line to individual plots, but I cannot find a way to combine the plots with normal lines:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

hist(DatT$H_PB, prob=T, breaks=10, col="red", xlab="Number of Hamma parent brood", main = "Parent Broods")
xfit<-seq(min(DatT$H_PB),max(DatT$H_PB),length=40)
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(DatT$H_PB),sd=sd(DatT$H_PB))
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(DatT$H_PB)
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)
hist(DatT$H_NOR, prob=T, breaks=10, col="red", xlab="Number of Hamma NOR", main = "Natural Origin Returns")
hist(DatT$MHC_PB, prob=T, breaks=10, col="red", xlab="Number of MHC parent brood", main = "")
hist(DatT$MHC_NOR, prob=T, breaks=10, col="red", xlab="Number of MHC NOR",  main = "")
```

Is there a way to combine these more complicated plots with par() or otherwise?  Thanks.